# How to mock a module method during detox testing?

Tags: javascript, react-native, detox

I'm trying mock a module during detox e2e testing :

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    function mockFunctions() {
      const original = require.requireActual('react-native-device-info');
      return {
        ...original,
        getDeviceCountry: jest.fn(() => {
          return 'DE'
        })
      }
    }
    await jest.mock('react-native-device-info', () => mockFunctions)
  })
```

It's not working, so I'm wondering if it's even possible?